# no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (void ())

Tags: c++

I'm trying to run 2 while loops in 2 different functions at the same time using Threads but i get an error like so::.
Error: `no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (void ())`
I tried joining and detaching threads but that didn't work either.

```
class Parallel {
    public:
    int attempts = 0;
    int rs = 0;
    int threads = 0;
    int before = 0;

    void RS(){
        while(true) {
            before = attempts;
            Sleep(1000);
            rs = attempts - before;
        }
    }

    void Print() {
        while(true) {
            attempts++;
            cout << "\r" << "Attempts: " << attempts << " RS: " << rs;
        }
    }

    void thread2(){

        thread first (Print());
        thread second (RS());
    }
};


int main(){
    Parallel j;
    j.thread2();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `thread first (&Parallel::Print, this);` or `thread first ([this]() { Print(); });` As written, your code calls `Print` on the main thread, then tries to pass its return value to `std::thread`; but it doesn't in fact return any value. Changing it the way I show would allow the code to compile; but there are many other problems with it.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to use a class?

Comment: @Shidouuu no it is not really important but i will use it in a later Project.

Comment: There are a number of fundamental flaws in the shown code that all must be fixed, before it'll work correctly. For example. Even if `first` and `second` get constructed correctly, since these objects are almost guaranteed to get destroyed while the execution thread still exists, `abort`() will bring everything to a quick end. You should start from scratch. Start with just a single thread function that does something innocuous. Get that working properly first. Only then move on to introduce more complexity, like classes, etc...